# format of mysql query log

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

What is the format of the mysql query log? In particular, for lines like:

```
133 Query     commit
133 Query     rollback
```

What does '133' stand for? And is it true that each line represents a round trip communication to the database (i.e., they are not batched)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A typical general log format looks like this:

```
Time              Id Command    Argument
110208 12:12:06   771 Query rollback
```

Multiple queries can appear at particular time-stamp also ID indicates MySQL connection thread id which has executed a query Command of type "Query" which indicates query has been executed and Argument is actually a query itself.

Answer (score 13):

In the [MySQL General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html), the fields are these:

```
yymmdd hh:mm:ss thread_id command_type query_body
```

The timestamp only appears each time it changes.

In your example "133" would be the thread id of the connected client, as shown in [`SHOW PROCESSLIST;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html).

Each line represents a query issued, but not necessarily a round-trip from the client to the database, because queries issued within stored procedures and stored functions are also logged, and a proc or function, while running, could issue many queries in response to a single query from a client.

Also, the MySQL C-API, which is the library underlying some languages' connectors to MySQL, supports [multiple statement execution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html), which would be another case where multiple queries don't necessarily represent multiple round-trips since multiple queries can be send to the database as a "batch"... but that's only a factor if this capability is used by the calling application.

The general log can also be directed to write to the `mysql.general_log` table, which is easier to parse and analyze than the file-based log, but the same general observations, above, apply when using that format.

The [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) includes more information and so provides a more informative log for understanding how the server is performing, and can be used as a log of *all* queries by configuring MySQL to interpret all queries as meeting the "slow" criteria.  This is done by setting [`long_query_time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) to '0' after enabling the slow query log.